# columnWrapperStyle not supported for single column list in FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a `Flatlist` with horizontal view that will load some items in single row. I am using `columnWrapperStyle` props to setting my Flatlist container but it give an `error` as below :

```
Invariant Violation: columnWrapperStyle not supported for single column lists
```

This is my `code` :

```
<View >
    <FlatList
      columnWrapperStyle={styles.flatListHomeContentContainerStyle}
      horizontal={true}
      data={prop1}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
      renderItem=...
      .....
    />
</View>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution to my own problem. Since `columnWrapperStyle` can't be used in FlatList horizontal, i need to apply my style to the child items inside `FlatList` which is using a prop `containerStyle` and its worked.

```
<FlatList
   horizontal={true}
   renderItem={({ item }) => (
   <Card 
   containerStyle={styles.flatListHomeContentContainerStyle}
   ...
   </Card>
</FlatList>
```

Answer (score 4):

`columnWrapperStyle` **applicable only** when there are **more than signle column** ,must satisfy condition  `numColumns > 1` .

it does not support for a single column that why it showing error.
Reference: [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#columnwrapperstyle)

Comment: ok its make sense. then how i am gonna put a style to my `Flatlist` since the margin between item inside the Flastlist was too far.

Comment: `columnWrapperStyle` will apply a style to the group of items. but if you have to less number of columns means you can apply the same style to a single item in `renderComponent`

Comment: my bad. i just found a solution. just apply a styles to `containerStyle` to my child item inside 'Flatlist' solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## contentContainerStyle

in flatlist horizontal the number of column is 1 so columnWrapperStyle will not be applicable.

use `contentContainerStyle`

example:

```
         <FlatList
          horizontal
          data={DATA}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          contentContainerStyle={{marginBottom: 10}}
         />
```